# Find a bijection between the two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

[image]

I know the function to find the number of bijections is $f(n) = f(n-1) * n$ where $f(n)$ is the number of bijections of $n$, and $n = |A|$, i.e the number of elements in the set (in this case, matching parentheses). But I have no idea where to go from here, I know it's not what the question is asking, can anyone help?

Comment: This is a job for Catalan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to obtain a parntheses sequence from a triangulated polygon (with one edge marked as "base") is as follows:

The base belongs to a triangle (except for the case of a 2-gon, which we represent by the empty parentehses string ""). Remove the triangle and you obtain two smaller  triangulated polygons, where you view the edge they share with the removed triangle as base. Now write down the parentheses sequence for the left polygon, followed by "(", the parentheses seqeunce for the right polygon, and ")".

In fact this method matches the examples in the picture (with the obvious choice of base) and it is instructive to verify this.

Can you find the inverse map, i.e. how to construct a polygon by "parsing" aparentheses string? And show that these maps are indeed inverse of each other?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you mean, like what do you mean the edge they share with the removed triangle as base? And how are the parentheses sequences supposed to be ordered?